# in anyone can explain why i can't run some command with user permission granted..?

Tags: macos, bash, operating-system, filesystems

So, simple question is that when i try to run **/sbin/ifconfig** without sudo, it can execute.

However if i try to run **/sbin/shutdown**, it says that i need to be a root..

But It has both permission for user to execute.

My question is that even though both command has the **permission for user**, how come one can be run and the other can not.?

What am i missing..? could you anyone explain why.. please..?

Thank you in advance..

ps: i'm running under mac..

Comment: Yes, that was my previous question sir. But, i didn't get the proper answer so i posted it again.. is there any way to update or refresh my previous question ..?

Comment: Simply press the `edit` link under the question, and make your edit.

Comment: The file system permissions for the program are not the issue here. You can run `/sbin/shutdown`. But one of the first things it does as it runs is check who you are, and refuse to continue if certain conditions are not met. Relying only on file system permissions for complete system security would be a bit lacking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even `ifconfig` will not perform any action as non-root. If you are executing it without any arguments it will just print the current state, which can be considered secure. If you are using it to change some network settings, it will require root permissions as `shutdown` does. This is because it will then attempt to write to files, which are writable by root only or perform other actions which are restricted to the root user.